# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError for small images

Tags: android

In app I'm working on you can choose between multiple backgrounds and every time when I select background for layout I'm setting it with

```
relativeLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
```

Each of the backgrounds have resolution of 1440x2560 pixels, but they only have around 12 KB each and bit depth 4.

Problem is that sometimes when I select background app crashes with error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: The file size is not relevant.  These images are large. 1440 x 2560 x 4 bytes is approx 11MB.

Comment: The images are probably around 12 MB, not 12 KB...

Answer (score 0):

Resize the image before loading

```
 public Bitmap resizeBitmap(int targetW, int targetH) {
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight; 
    int scaleFactor = 1;
    if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) { 
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH); 
    }
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, bmOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is quite simple. You need to recycle the bitmap everytime you change it by clicking the button, or else it will stay in memory and eventually throw the out of memory exception.

Anyways, if you want to fix this, keep a reference to your bitmap on your activity.

private Bitmap currentBitmap;

```
public void changeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
  relativeLayout.setBackgroundImage(bitmap);
  if(currentBitmap != null){    
  /*this is where the magic happens, you                
  recycle your old bitmap whose reference you had stored in the global 
  variable*/
    currentBitmap.recycle();
  }
  currentBitmap = bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The quckfix is `android:largeHeap="true"` in the AndroidManifest in `<application>`
But I think it needs a lot of RAM to show the Drawable on the Screen. The Dirty Fix is, when you call the garbage collector programmatically.

I am still searching for the clean fix.

Comment: Android says largeheap doesn't work always and in such a case where user is loading large resolution image it will result in out of memory exception. We should resize the image before loading

Comment: Calling GC will do nothing.